# Do you have any advice for sending PointCloud2 over a wireless nework

Tags: ros, wifi, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to send the PointCloud2 topic through a wireless network. Is there already some implementation in ros I am missing? Any good link you would recommend?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9638/do-you-have-any-advice-for-sending-pointcloud2-over-a-wireless-nework/) by [MlabKinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/257/mlabkinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just start your publisher on one machine and the subscriber on another, as described in [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines). This is not specific to wireless networks.

In case you have to limit the bandwidth, have a look at the [topic_tools stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/), especially the [throttle node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/throttle).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't need high pointcloud density you could downsample it first before publishing. (Voxelgrid).

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that all channels in your point cloud are useful for the posterior processing/visualization. Remove them in other case.
Decreasing the dimensionality of your data should be always one the first choices when performance problems appear.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1